# How to trigger the update on entity in spring data?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I have two entity employee and Salary, I want my salary entity should updated whenever there is change in Employee Entity role property.
Employee Entity:
emp_id
name
Role
Salary Entity:
id
emp_id
SalarySlab

I need to automatically update the salary slab whenever there is any change in role of employee.
I am not able get the proper approach to achieve this in spring data/jpa

Comment: If your Salary depends on Role then Salary should be part of Role not Employee. If your salary is a  calculated field it should not be in the database but come for a calculated field or service.

Comment: @Snickers3192 role is the field of employee entity. I need to evaluate some other field also from the employee table and want to update my salary table whenever there is update on employee table

Comment: I'm just saying that you shouldn't have any calculated fields in your database.

Comment: You would just have  a Service annotated with `@Transactional` otherwise but again, you shouldn't have anything like calculated sallary etc in the database. Any field which is purely created from a combination of other fields but holds no actual state shouldn't be in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume You have a `@OneToOne` relation between `Employee` and `Salary`, so your `Employee` entity has a **salary** field annotated properly. For example:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")
private Salary salary;
```

More about entity relation mapping [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne).

The simplest solution is that You have to put this logic in the **role** setter. For example:

```
void setRole(Role newRole) { 
    this.role = newRole;
    updateSalary();
}

void updateSalary() { ... }
```

If you have no setter method for that field - which I would not recommend - You can use JPA's `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotations. For example:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
public void updateSalary() { ... }
```

This way `updateSalary` will be called every time spring creates a new `Employee` entity or updates an existing one. More about lifecycle callbacks' hibernate implemantation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html).